# RxJava JUnit test with Retrofit throws a NullPointerException

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have a retrofit2 API call

```
public interface FeedService {
    @GET("/api/v1/feeds")
    Observable<FeedResponse> getFeeds(@Query("page") Integer pageNumber,
                                          @Query("cats") String categories,
                                          @Query("lang") String language);
}
```

I have a Repository which uses this API like so-

```
public class FeedRepositoryImpl implements FeedRepository {
    private static FeedRepositoryImpl INSTANCE;
    private int FIRST_PAGE = 1;
    private FeedService feedService;

    public static FeedRepositoryImpl getFeedRepository(FeedService feedService) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new FeedRepositoryImpl(feedService);
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Feed> getFeeds(final int pageNumber, final String categories, final String
            language) {
        return feedService.getFeeds(pageNumber, categories, language)
                .concatMap(new Function<FeedResponse, ObservableSource<? extends Feed>>() {
                    @Override
                    public ObservableSource<? extends Feed> apply(FeedResponse feedResponse) throws
                            Exception {
                        return Observable.fromIterable(feedResponse.feedsData());
                    }
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to write JUnit tests which verify that the `FeedService's` `getFeeds()` is called with the same arguments that are used to call `FeedRepository.getFeeds()`.

However, I am getting a `NullPointerException`. Here is what my test looks like -

```
public class FeedRepositoryImplTest {

    private static String CATEGORIES = "feeds?page=1&cats=top,yt,world,ent,ls,sp";
    private static String LANGUAGE = "lang=en";
    private static int PAGE_NUMBER = 1;

    @Rule
    public ImmediateSchedulersRule immediateSchedulersRule = new ImmediateSchedulersRule();
    @Mock
    FeedService feedService;
    FeedRepositoryImpl feedRepository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        feedRepository = FeedRepositoryImpl.getFeedRepository(feedService);
    }

    @Test
    public void getFeeds() throws Exception {
        // arrange
        Observable<Feed> emptyFeed = Observable.empty();
        when(feedRepository.getFeed(PAGE_NUMBER, CATEGORIES, LANGUAGE))
                .thenReturn(emptyFeed);

        // act
        feedRepository.getFeed(PAGE_NUMBER, CATEGORIES, LANGUAGE);

        System.out.println("feedRepository.getFeeds(PAGE_NUMBER, CATEGORIES, LANGUAGE)");
        // assert
        verify(feedService).getFeeds(PAGE_NUMBER, CATEGORIES, LANGUAGE);
    }
}
```

My `TestRule` looks like this -

```
public class ImmediateSchedulersRule implements TestRule {
    @Override
    public Statement apply(final Statement base, Description description) {
        return () -> {
                RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler((scheduler) -> {
                        return Schedulers.trampoline();
                });
                RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler((scheduler) -> {
                        return Schedulers.trampoline();
                });
                RxJavaPlugins.setNewThreadSchedulerHandler((scheduler) -> {
                        return Schedulers.trampoline();
                });
                RxAndroidPlugins.setMainThreadSchedulerHandler((scheduler) -> {
                        return Schedulers.trampoline();
                });
                RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler((schedulerCallable) -> {
                        return Schedulers.trampoline();
                });
                base.evaluate();
        };
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown at this line -

```
.concatMap(new Function<FeedResponse, ObservableSource<? extends Feed>>() { ... }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to `mock` a method of `FoodRepositoryImpl` which is a real object (using the mocked `feedService`).

change:

```
feedRepository = FeedRepositoryImpl.getFeedRepository(feedService);
```

to

```
feedRepository = Mockito.spy(FeedRepositoryImpl.getFeedRepository(feedService));
```

---

EDIT:

You should just change the method mock to (spying `FeedRepositoryImpl` doesn`t matter):

```
when(feedService.getFeeds(PAGE_NUMBER, CATEGORIES, LANGUAGE)).thenReturn(emptyFeed);
```

Comment: Could you explain this in more detail? I tried this but still have the same `NullPointerException` at `feedService.getFeeds().concatMap()`.

Comment: Sure thing. You're calling `when(feedRepository.getFeed(PAGE_NUMBER, CATEGORIES, LANGUAGE)).thenReturn(emptyFeed);` which means that you're trying to mock a method of the `feedRepository` object. Mockito is unable to mock methods on real objects. Mockito is able to do that either on fully mocked objects (using `@Mock` or `Mockito.mock`) or wrapped real objects (using `Mockito.spy`).

Comment: The only object you mocked is the `feedService`. You created `feedRepository` in a normal way (using the mocked `feedService`).

Comment: I removed the `when/then` clause itself for the `feedRepository` and did a `when/then` on `feedService`(as you said that it is the thing that is mocked not the feedRepository) and it seems to work.

Comment: feedRepository = Mockito.spy(FeedRepositoryImpl.getFeedRepository(feedService));

does now work. I still get the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: you will need to paste the code you're actually using. what is `newsFeedRepository`

Comment: if you're mocking `getFeed` on `feedService` instead of on `feedRepository`, then you don't have to `spy` that anymore.

Comment: I am sorry for that, `newsFeedRepository` and `feedRepository` are that same variable. I have edited the questions.

Comment: Alright, I edited the answer so we're on the same page. If after changing that, you're still getting `NPE` try setting `when/thenReturn` before creating `feedRepository` instance.